# Update OpenSSL to be used on built-in PHP-server on Mac 10.9.5

Tags: php, macos, openssl

I tried updating an old php-version (5.4.3) on mac OSX server because I need a newer version of OpenSSL (eg. 1.0.0 or 1.0.1). Updating php went succesfully, but the old version of OpenSSL is still in this php version...
The result of command 'openssl version' is 'OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017', so OK!
But the result of phpinfo() is 'Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) PHP/5.4.45 mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/0.9.8zg DAV/2'.

I'm running Server.app on MacOS 10.9.5.
But installing a separate version of Apache and PHP is possible. But how can I do this? I'm new with server administration, but familiar with web development.

How Can I use php with this newer OpenSSL (at least 1.0.0) included?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Comment: You have to build PHP from sources. There is nothing available that is binary compatible with OpenSSL 0.9.8. *"... because I need a newer version of OpenSSL (eg. 1.0.0 or 1.0.1)"* - You should use OpenSSL 1.0.2 or 1.1.0. The versions you selected are End-of-Life (EOL).

Comment: Thanks for your Reply. I Just want to use a newer version of OpenSSL (“openssl version” says I have a newer version installed, but PHP isn’t using this never version. Please Can you give me the steps to get php Working with this New OpenSSL? (A few step by step explaination to ‘build PHP from sources’)?

Comment: Since your mod_ssl compiled with old OpenSSL that's why phpinfo() shows old OpenSSL version. To fix that, you have to recompile your mod_ssl with latest OpenSSL installed.